# javascript clashing with virtuemart

Tags: javascript, joomla

Hi I believe i am having a javascript clash issue and I cannot find out where or what it is.

If you go to the website below

```
http://103.14.141.156/~wwwbetac/index.php/en/
```

and scroll over the menu a dropdown will appear. when you go to click on a dropdown menu item it will allow you to do this perfectly fine.

however when I click on "Our Products" or "Our Brands" the dropdown option still works but then when you go to click on a dropdown menu item it stops working.

I am using Joomla 2.5.14, Virtuemart 2.0.22a and the virtuemart template im using is Flexible VM2 Template from flexiblewebdesign.com I use yootheme for my joomla template and that template is yoo_balance and with yootheme im using widgetkit for my banners at the top (not sure if thats clashing or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be fancybox issue.

correct the following code:

```
jQuery('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
```

Comment: sorry akki, may I ask where I put this? in what file?

Comment: @Callum : I am not sure, but looking at the source code it seems to be in your main index file. I can see that your issue has been resolved, what was the issue?

Comment: I probably just cheated a little but I moved the dropdown menu up.